# Calling GWT from jsp page

Tags: gwt

I am totally new to GWT concept and JSP. Right now i need to call a gwt application from my login.jsp .
So how can i achieve this. I am building a gwt-java project using eclipse and compiling it.
Now what all i need to do is just call a .nocache file(which is obtained from gwt compilation) from my login.jsp..

I found one link based on this but i was totally confused

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7609

can any one help me in how to do this...
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 2):

After login form submission you can dispatch the page(`gwtDispatcher.jsp`) in your `LoginServlet`.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/gwtDispatcher.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

if you want to debug the code in development mode you have to add the query parameter

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/gwtDispatcher.jsp?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997")
                                                    .forward(request, response);
```

In  your gwtDispatcher.jsp  by adding the line

`<script language="javascript" src="../yourAppName.nocache.js"></script>`//make sure of  the path,you can dispatch the `gwt` program.

Comment: Well.. Here you have said that after submission i need to load gwt app via loginServlet... But thing is I dont want to deal with loginServelt..! My scenario is I have a login.jsp which contains a "change password" link.. on click of this link i need to load my gwt app...  So can you please guide me in this...  Thanks for your previous answer..!

Comment: Same thing...on href of of that link call servlet and dispatch fron forgootpassword servlet.

Answer (score -1):

I guess https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/dynamic_host_page will answer all your questions.